# Making django server accessible in LAN

Tags: python, django

I have installed Django server and it can be accessed as below

```
http://localhost:8000/get-sms/
http://127.0.0.1:8000/get-sms/
```

suppose My IP is `x.x.x.x` .

From another PC under the same network when I do

```
my-ip:8000/get-sms/
```

but it is not working.

I can easily ping my IP with that computer.

Moreover, on my port 81, I have apache, which is easily accessible like below

```
http:///my-ip:81
```

What can be the issue? Do I need something extra in Django

Comment: You can either configure your apache to forward things to your localhost:8000 or bind your development server to your lan ip.

Comment: do you use python manage.py runserver?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make Django's devserver public ? Is it generally possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328926/how-to-make-djangos-devserver-public-is-it-generally-possible)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the local Django webserver from outside world](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260727/how-to-access-the-local-django-webserver-from-outside-world)

Answer (score 145, accepted):

[Running the Django Development Server](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/django-admin/#runserver)
This is what you're looking for. To help you further, here is what you should do:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

By the way, this may be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260727/accessing-local-django-webserver-from-outside-world) question.

Here is what the documentation says:

> Note that the default IP address, 127.0.0.1, is not accessible from
>   other machines on your network. To make your development server
>   viewable to other machines on the network, use its own IP address
>   (e.g. 192.168.2.1) or 0.0.0.0.

Comment: @Depado  IP address 0.0.0.0 is a special address, which means default route, when used in terms of networking. Hence when I run my Django server on 0.0.0.0 the browser says "Invalid address". 
Moreover the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` is set to "*".

Any solution?

Comment: You should access the server using the IP of the machine on which it runs. Accessing it locally should be done using `127.0.0.1` otherwise you use the IP of the machine it runs on. I don't know if that's clear :/
That technique basically allows external connections.

Answer (score 14):

To add to @Depado 's answer you may need to add your LAN IP address to `ALLOWED_HOSTS` in the  `settings.py` along with  `localhost`. it would look like,

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["localhost", "192.168.8.160"]
```

(if `localhost` isn't working use `127.0.0.1` as suggested by @Sabito 錆兎)

Comment: Note: replace "localhost" with "127.0.0.1" if your local host stops working. (or add it in there too)

Answer (score 4):

You can use https://ngrok.com/ this will expose your local web server to the internet/public.

Comment: Hey those are nice tools ! Especially ngrok. Thanks for those tools !

Comment: I tried **ngrok** and it worked as I expected. Nice to try :)

Comment: Using an SSH tunnel won't fix an already non-accessible local server.

Answer (score 1):

Everywhere I looked, I kept seeing the answer to use the terminal command:

`python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

That works, but not if you want to run a remote debugger across the LAN (in my case VSCode), which launches the server automatically without a chance to modify the host ip address. However, I found a permanent solution:

Open: `./env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py`

Search for: `self.addr = ''`

Replace `''` with `'0'` and save. *(`'0'` is shorthand for `'0.0.0.0'`)*

Now if you run: `python manage.py runserver` it is open to the local network, outputting: `Starting development server at http://0:8000/`

Importantly, the debugger now launches the server at `http://0:8000/`

If you haven't already, remember to add your client to allowed hosts in settings.py: `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]`

> Blockquote