# How to share localhost port over local network

Tags: django, networking, localhost, port

I created webpage on local server with django framework (python). I have acces to it under address http://localhost:8000/. Now I want to share it over local network. I try to do it with Windows firewall Inbound/outbound rules, but it seems either I do something wrong or it's not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how to suggest a duplicate question, but seems your question have an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22144189/making-django-server-accessible-in-lan). Basically, you need to ask the django program to accept connection from the outside world by

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Comment: You may also need to add to allowed hosts in settings.py.

Answer (score 3):

To access a Django project running on a local network, you have to `runserver` with 0.0.0.0 as IP

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

and then set

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["localhost", "yours_host_ip_aaddress"]
```

that should work if your firewall allows!